# find command format behaves differently from ~/bin then from ./

Tags: bash

A script with the line

```
find [somedirectory]/ -ctime +1 -printf %f" "
```

behaves just fine (returns file names without the directories).
I run with:

```
./[somescript]
```

If I call it from ~/bin/, as in, simply

```
[somescript]
```

it finds the files but does not format the output?

Expected Output:

```
File1 File2 File3
```

Observed output from ~/bin/:

```
/directory/File1
/directory/File2
/directory/File3
```

Comment: What do you mean, "does not format the output"? Expected and observed output for both examples would be helpful.

Comment: Could you share some example output?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this with GNU find 4.5.10 - what version of `find` are you using?